# proper way of using es6 classes in a nodejs project

Tags: node.js, class, ecmascript-6

I'd like to be able to use the cool es6 classes feature of nodejs 4.1.2

I created the following project:

a.js:

```
class a {
  constructor(test) {
   a.test=test;
  }
}
```

index.js:

```
require('./a.js');
var b = new a(5);
```

as you can see I create a simple class that it's constructor gets a parameter. and in my include i require that class and create a new object based on that class. pretty simple.. but still i'm getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ufk/work-projects/bingo/server/bingo-tiny/index.js:1:63)
at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
```

any ideas why ?

Comment: [Strict mode](https://devdocs.io/javascript/functions_and_function_scope/strict_mode)

Comment: don't i need to enable strict mode? it's not enabled by default no ?

Comment: You need to enable strict mode, it's not (yet) enabled by default.

Comment: i added "use strict"; at the beginning of index.js but the results are the same

Comment: You need it at the beginning of every module.

Comment: thank you. i'll paste the answer

Comment: `a.test=test;` doesn't make sense btw.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

i'm still confused about why 'use strict' is needed, but this is the code that works:

index.js:

```
"use strict"; 
var a = require('./a.js');
var b = new a(5);
```

a.js:

```
"use strict";
class a {
 constructor(test) {
  a.test=test;
 } 
}
module.exports=a;
```

Comment: *"i'm still confused about why 'use strict' is needed"* I think the error message is pretty clear, isn't it? "*Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode"* You need it because `class` is not yet supported outside of strict mode.

Answer (score 36):

Or you can run like this:

`node --use_strict index.js`

Comment: Much better than putting "use strict" in the scripts. Also, the order of arguments seems to matter: `node index.js --use_strict` does *not* work.

Comment: Running your entire app in strict mode means you won't be able to use modules that assume you are not running in strict mode. You may find yourself doing a lot of refactoring down the line if you do this.