# Can I set "strict mode" for js as a global parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mocha.js, remap-istanbul

I have a typescript project that is using Mocha to generate coverage. I would like to convert the coverage back to the typescript files using `remap-istanbul`, however I keep on getting this error when I try to run remap-istanbul on my coverage:

```
SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
```

I've googled the issue and the two options I've found are either changing the compliation to "ES5" rather than "ES6" (which I cannot do as my tests will fail if I change it to ES5) or adding `"use strict";` inside the block of code (which I cannot do because it is not my project).

Are there any other ways of getting around this issue?

Comment: This has been answered fairly well by this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391760/use-strict-needed-in-a-typescript-file

Comment: I want it set for the javascript project remap-instanbul that I'm trying to run though, not my own typescript project.

Comment: Oh I think I misread the question.  You can run node with `--use_strict` to force strict mode
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33063206/proper-way-of-using-es6-classes-in-a-nodejs-project

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Use Strict" needed in a TypeScript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391760/use-strict-needed-in-a-typescript-file)